# Python to_datetime produces wrong date

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

I'm using Python to convert a column in my dataframe to a datetime format (which is initially loaded from a CSV file and in object format).

After loading...

```
data.info()
```

...results in Date 2142 non-null object. Using...

```
data['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d/%m/%y')
```

...does indeed produce a datetime column, but the date gets messed up. The first two rows, for instance, are as follows:

```
Date     Date1
26/08/16 2017-08-18
27/08/16 2017-08-19
```

As you can see, both columns have nothing in common. I get the same result when I leave out the format element.
How can I get the correct date after using to_datetime?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/2848256 check here

Comment: At least in my pandas pd.to_datetime('26/08/16', format='%d/%m/%y') gives Timestamp('2016-08-26 00:00:00'), the version is 0.23.4

Comment: Could you please indicate the version of your environment (python and pandas)?